# When is the message about not having voted on questions given?

Tags: support, voting, popups

On a Stack Exchange site, I voted some questions (between 5 or 6 questions, at least), then I started voting some answers, and I got a message about voting on questions too, which was similar to "you have not voted for questions in a while," and that suggested I should vote on questions too. Since I kept voting on answers after a pause, I got the same message again, and then again; I even got it twice in row, for two votes on answers. (I don't remember the exact words because instinctively I clicked to close the dialog box; that is why I said that is similar too, even if those could be the exact used words.)

I have seen that message when, in a day, I started voting for answers, and voted for X answers in row, without voting questions. In this case, I started with voting questions, and I also voted on questions the day I voted on that site.

Is that message only given when the system is deciding if I can vote more than 30 times?
I ask because the used words suggests me I didn't vote for questions in the last 5-6 days, while I did it right today, and the day I voted on that site before today. I understand that the message is considering a relatively short period of time, or having voted on 1225 questions and 779 answers would be considered, but I would imagine I should not get that message if I have voted for questions during the day.

Should not the message be changed, or showed in different circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [blag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/):

> ...if you haven’t voted on at least one question in the last 15 votes
> you cast — you’ll now get the “you haven’t voted on questions in a
> while; questions need votes too!” reminder every time you vote until
> you do.

I'm not sure how up-to-date this info is, as the rules may have been tweaked over time (that blog post is from May 2011).

I think part of the confusion comes from the subjective nature of "*in a while*".  In this case, I don't think it's refering to time.  The meaning is more like:

> you haven’t voted on questions in <strike>a while</strike> the past
> several votes; questions need votes too!

Comment: Basing on that, if I vote for 10 questions, and then for 16 answers, I would get that message because my last 15 votes were for answers. It is not what I would call "not voting for questions in a wile." `:)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno Correct.  The wording does seem a bit misleading / flawed now that you mention it =)

Comment: @kiamlaluno I've updated my answer with a little bit of a clarification (hopefully).

Comment: I agree that _in a while_ can be subjective, but I don't think somebody would tell me "you have not taken out the trash in a while" if I did that in the morning. `:)`